# Jquery Event Handling Question

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(".foo").click(processFooClick);
}
```

Once the document has loaded, then via javascript I dynamically add a new div with `foo` class to the document:

```
$("body").append( "<div class='foo'>click..</div>");
```

Would this new div also have the event handler automatically applied to it, or would I need to run the event setting code ( $(".foo").click(...) ) again?

Would using jquery's `live` function help with this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method would not work, take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/esN4Q/

But, `live` would:

```
$(".foo").live('click', processFooClick);
```

jsFiddle Example of jQuery `live`: http://jsfiddle.net/ePmXU/ (I added an alert pop up in the jsFiddle so we can see if it works when it's clicked.)

Comment: @ClickUpvote Nope, `.live('click')` works just like .click, except it works even after you add an element dynamically :) You can learn more about .live here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2):

The new div will *not* have the event handler attached to it. `live` will allow it to work as you described:

```
$(".foo").live('click', processFooClick);
```

But, I'd just add the event handler to the new div again. You shouldn't use `live` unless you really don't control when new elements are added to the page.

Comment: if you do add the click to the new div,  make sure you are only adding it to that div, and not all with the foo class or the first ones will run the handler twice

Comment: @MattoTodd: that's true, the event should _only_ be attached to the newly created element.

Answer (score 2):

click() is a shortcut for bind(). bind will attach directly to the matching elements. That means, no, your new element will not have a handler. Using $(".foo").live(processClick) will work, because live() works by attaching a handler to the document and catching bubbled-up events. Also look at delegate() for a more scoped live type of event handler.

Answer (score 2):

When event handlers are added, they are added to the elements themselves, so adding new matching elements will not result in them having the event handlers.  I believe you can re-assign the handlers.

Using .live() avoids this problem - I believe that (paraphrasing) events are handled on the fly, and if an element matches it it applied.  You can add elements as needed and they will handle any events that have been applied to matching elements.

Answer (score 2):

`live` would work, but your first method would not (if you add the div after the first `click` function was run)

If you decide to call click again, you need to make sure you are not adding the click handler twice to all your original `foo` divs, or they will be run twice

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you probably need to use live as your click event registration is done after DOMs are loaded. Any dynamically generated DOM won't get that event handler so you have to use live. In this case, something like:

```
$(".foo").live('click', processFooClick);
```

Or if you have a narrower context scope:

```
$(".foo", $(someContext)[0]).live('click', processFooClick);
```